# jQuery Selector to Select Sections of a Table

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have the following table in my page

```
<table>
<tr class="evenPack">
</tr>
<tr class="evenSubPack">
</tr>
<tr class="evenSubPack">
</tr>
<tr class="evenSubPack">
</tr>
<tr class="evenSubPack">
</tr>
<tr class="oddPack">
</tr>
<tr class="oddSubPack">
</tr>
<tr class="oddSubPack">
</tr>
<tr class="oddSubPack">
</tr>
<tr class="oddSubPack">
</tr>
<tr class="evenPack">
</tr>
<tr class="evenSubPack">
</tr>
<tr class="evenSubPack">
</tr>
<tr class="evenSubPack">
</tr>
<tr class="evenSubPack">
</tr>
</table>
```

The evenPack rows and oddPack rows are clickable. When the user clicks on one of them, I want the immediate SubPack rows to toggleSlide().

for example, if the user clicks on the first row, which is a evenPack. Then only the four evenSubPack rows that are immediately after the first evenPack should toggleSlide. It shouldn't toggleSlide() the evenSubPack rows that are at the bottom of the table.

I can't think of the selector to do this.

Comment: I'll just throw this in a comment rather than an answer. There is no selector to do this, I would suggest going through a loop of all the 'tr's after the one that is clicked and toggleSlide() them until you hit one of a different class. Then just break the loop and you are done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nextUntil() for this:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
    var active =  $(this).attr("class").indexOf('even') > -1 ? 'odd' : 'even';
    //find if the clike in even, and find out out the next stop point will be
    $(this).nextUntil('.' + active + 'Pack').slideToggle();
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/GEZZw/)

Answer (score 1):

[`nextUntil` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) is your friend:

```
$('.evenPack, .oddPack').click(function() {
    var mod = this.className.indexOf('even') > -1 ? 'odd' : 'even';
    $(this).nextUntil('.' + mod + 'Pack').slideToggle();
});
```

If there are other rows in between `.evenPack` and `.oddPack`, you can filter the `.*SubPack` elements by passing a second argument to `nextUntil`:

```
$(this).nextUntil('.' + mod + 'Pack', '.' + (mod === 'even' ? 'odd' : 'even') + 'SubPack').slideToggle();
```

If `.evenPack` and `.oddPack` rows are always alternating, you could also do:

```
var $elements = $('.evenPack, .oddPack')
$elements.click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil($elements.get($elements.index(this) + 1)).slideToggle();
});
```

This works since the elements are selected in the order they appear in the document. So instead of searching for the next element with class `evenPack` or `oddPack`, it just takes the next element in the selected set.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VCsR5/) *(note that `.slideToggle` does not seem to work properly with table rows (they don't slide))*

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer. Saved a lot of hassle for me. It just works.Starx, thanks for you too mate